# factor name(s): as.factor(rastername) not in layer namesError in `[.data.frame`(blockvals, , f[j]) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, raster, categorical-data, gam, continuous

I have built a GAM model, with a mix of continuous and catergorical variables, obtained from sampling points in 4 rasters- (1) MODIS burn product where I counted the number of times a pixel burnt in the period 1989-2019 and then collapsed it to a binary raster with pixels that did not burn=0 and remaining pixels i.e. that burnt=1

(2) sand fraction % from World ISRIC (no changes made)

(3) mean annual precipitation from CHIRPS for same tim eperiod

(4) mean dry season length as the number of months in a year that have preci lesser than 10% of the annual precip of that year.

All variables were projected, cropped and masked based on my study area. The response variable is the MODIS treecover%. All rasters were sampled for 1500 points based on two strata and different masks to exclude certain land uses and covers (from Global Land Cover 2000 dataset).

After referring to all the links in this [Stack exchange post titled 'GAM in R with categorical AND continuous variables'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49324297/gam-in-r-with-categorical-and-continuous-variables), I followed the [blogpost From the bottom of the heap, titled 'Comparing smooths in factor-smooth interactions II ordered factors'](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2017/12/14/difference-splines-ii/). I used the exact same code and syntax mentioned in the blogpost (literally copy pasted) and converted the burn column that has 0s and 1s in the dataframe, df to two levels 'noburn' and 'burn' with 'noburn' being the reference and named it the column oFire. I then ran multiple different models listed below to tease the effect of the three predictors- mean annual precip, sand fraction% and dry season length in burnt and unburnt areas.

```
model1_onlymap<-gam(modis_treecover ~ s(map), data=df, method='REML')

model2_map_burn<-gam(modis_treeciver ~ oFire+s(map) + s(map, by=oFire), data=df, method='REML'

model3_map_dsl_burn<-gam(modis_treecover ~oFire +s(map)+s(dry season length) +s(map, by=oFire)+ s(dry season length, by=oFire), data=df, method='REML')

model4_map_dsl_sand_burn<-gam(modis_treecover ~oFire +s(map)+s(dry season length)+ s(sand)+s(map, by=oFire)+ s(dry season length, by=oFire) +s(sand, by=oFire), data=df, method='REML')
```

At this stage, I chose the last model to be the model I want to continue working with. After completing the model, tuning/assessing it with gam.check(), concurvity(), plots etc., I decided to predict it to my study area.

Alternatively, I also built each GAM model keeping the burn column in my df as 0 and 1 and treating it as a factor, to understand the differences in the results of the two ways to treat categorical variables.

Obviosuly, I do not have a burn raster with pixel values- 'noburn' and 'burn'. As mentioned, it is a binary raster with pixel values 0 and 1. So I continued to make a stack of the four predictor variables. For the purposes of prediction, I excluded the 'oFire' column from the df and built a model

```
gam_for_prediction<-gam(modis_treecover~ modis_burn + s(map)+s(dsl)+s(sand)+s(map, by=as.factor(modis_burn))+s(dsl, by=as.factor(modis_burn))+s(sand, by=as.factor(modis_burn)), data=df, method='REML')
```

The last model treating burn as ordinal factors and this model above for prediction is the same, except the interpretation of the plots and understanding the content in the summary() of the two models is slightly different. So I decided to use this gam_for_prediction model for the final prediction to my study area, after which I get the error.

```
factor name(s): as.factor(modis_burn)  not in layer namesError in `[.data.frame`(blockvals, , f[j]) : undefined columns selected
```

What I did-
I read all raster names with the same names used in the model. I still get the same error with var4.
I read the burn raster (a binary raster as mentioned) and forced it to be as a factor using

```
modis_burn@data@values<- as.factor(modis_burn@data@values)
```

What am I doing wrong with var4? How do I get the prediction to work? T

Except for soil ISRIC data, all data was prepped in GEE and exported. If needed I can upload my rasters, csv with the 1500 sampled points and complete script separately.

EDIT-

I took the hint from @Gavin Simpson about predict() trying to search for a variable called as.factor (modis_burn) literally, when in fact the variable is called modis_burn. So for the prediction section, I speciefied the GAM model as-

```
gam_for_prediction<-gam(modis_treecover~modis_burn+s(map)+s(dry season length)+s(sand fraction)+s(map, by=modis_burn)+s(dsl, by=modis_burn)+s(sand, by=modis_burn), df=data (without the ordinal 'noburn'/ 'burn' column), method=REML)
```

Then I predicted

```
predict(predictor stack, gam_for_prediction, type='response')
```

And it worked! I was able to predict to my newdata aka raster stack of my predictors of my study area

Comment: can you please create a minimal self-contained reproducible example?

Comment: @RobertHijmans- thank you for your comment! added more details.

Comment: There's no way that GAM ever fitted with the code for the model you showed. Please paste the actual model formula, not syntactically incorrect pseudo code. Also, you don't have `modis_burn` as a factor fixed effect in the model so I wouldn't trust this model. Finally, don't coerce variables to factors etc in the formula. It is very easy to get into a situation where the `predict()` code is looking for variables named (literally!) `"as.factor(modis_burn)"` rather than `"modis_burn"`, which clearly don't exist. Prep you data first, *then* fit the model.

Comment: @GavinSimpson- I added more details as you suggested and also found the solution.